# Where is the DayZ saved game file located?

Tags: dayz-2012

I'm planning on formatting my hard drive and deal with all the hassle that comes with it. My one concern is, where is the saved game file for DayZ? Will I be able to transfer it to my fresh new install of Windows, or will I have to start a new character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DayZ character is stored server-side and is linked to your CD-Key.  As long as you are playing with the same CD-key, you will have access to your character.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on OrigamiRobot:

The DayZ 'team' has what's called a 'Hive.' Think of this as a central database where everyone's character data is stored.. that is, your coordinates, your inventory, stats, everything.

The only thing that is local to you is your ARMA profile. For example: Player Name/Skin/Squad data.

You'll notice if you ever have joined a 'private' server that you have to start on the bean coast, this is because each private server has it's own local 'hive.'

Your dayz hive data is based on your CD-Key.  If you were to buy Arma on a different steam account you could essentially have 2 DayZ characters.

Comment: *"The only thing that is local to you is your ARMA profile"* - so where is that located, then?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - Depends on the operating system, easy enough to find, search for the folder in `My Documents`

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update this entry with the new standalone finally coming out. I am having the same issue as the original poster and have been trying to find the answer, with everyone telling me that a character is linked server side with my game.

I would like to note that server characters are BS for standalone, at least as of 01/25/14. I reformatted my hard drive and installed DayZ Standalone and my character was wiped, even on the same server that I was playing on earlier that day. I had no troubles with character loss any time before reformatting and I logged out in the same way that I always did.

I just wanted to give this warning to anyone who needs to reformat their system or wants to install DayZ on a new device. Sorry to bump a 2 year old post but this was the only thing I could find that was related to my issue. Hopefully if someone comes across this post with the same issues as me this can help them, but unfortunately I cannot find where characters are saved.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to find your DAYZ Folder and there are some documents DayZ.cfg, Player.cfg and some others maybe You need to backup this DayZ folder. Mydocuments>DayZ>config. But carefull i did not testet it now in 0.51 but it worked in 0.45